# Merge tags n2 and n2cms

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The tags [n2](/questions/tagged/n2) and [n2cms](/questions/tagged/n2cms) are both about the "lightweight CMS built on top of ASP.NET". They serve exactly the same purpose.

I propose to merge them into [n2](/questions/tagged/n2). Or create a synonym (not sure how that works).

Comment: Not sure, but I think you're right about merging into `n2`. We don't have a `sql-serverDBMS` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I agree the tags have the same meaning. I would rather use [n2cms](/questions/tagged/n2cms) because [n2](/questions/tagged/n2) is too short, but if there isn't any possibility that [n2](/questions/tagged/n2) could be used with another meaning, [n2](/questions/tagged/n2) is fine too.

Normally we don't add *cms* to a tag that is about a CMS; in fact, there is [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal), not [drupal-cms](/questions/tagged/drupal-cms), or [drupalcms](/questions/tagged/drupalcms), although Drupal is a CMS. It was necessary to use [django-cms](/questions/tagged/django-cms), and [django](/questions/tagged/django), as [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com) is different from [Django CMS](https://www.django-cms.org).

Answer (score 1):

With 48 and 52 posts currently tagged under [n2](/questions/tagged/n2) and [n2cms](/questions/tagged/n2cms) respectively, manual retagging can also be applied. `n2` looks fine but a better tag name could be `n2-cms` similar to [django-cms](/questions/tagged/django-cms).

Comment: I tried to rename n2cms to n2-cms on a particular question, but then SO complains it already has a tag n2cms... How to introduce that dash?

Comment: Catch 22, you can't. Lets retag all posts to `n2`. Once there is no post under `n2cms`, it will be automatically removed from the system. Then we can request for a tag synonym `n2-cms` for `n2`.